# worksheet_calculate is stuck in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

i'm trying to use a formulated cell "F42" to return a value of 1 everytime conditions are met to trigger an event. when the conditions are met it starts looping. i need to be able to trigger this event up to 3-4 times through out the day. i'm guessing i need to create some sort of stored values. but not sure how to go about it. here's what i have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    On Error GoTo skipallthis
    If Range("F42").Value > 0 Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Call BuyConditions
       Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
 skipallthis:
 End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "it starts looping"?  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: After you have done what you need your VBA to do, try setting the value of "F40 back to something <=0.  Other wise its your code will execute again next time the sheet recalculates since F40 is still >0

Comment: I'm going to guess that your sub `BuyConditions` changes the value in `F42`, in which case the `Worksheet_Calculate` is called.

Comment: In light of Bruce's comment you could change the value of F42 immediately after the if statement and before calling any functions/subs

Comment: i want to thank everyone for your input.i took a long look at it and saw how i could change one of the conditional values in the code so it wouldn't continue holding the value and forcing the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    On Error GoTo skipallthis
    If Range("F42").Value > 0 Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Call BuyConditions

```
   'changing this value will prevent the buy conditions from being met
   Sheet6.Range("L32").Value = 1

   Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

skipallthis:
 End Sub